# Using multiple queries and render to HTML

Tags: html, node.js, sql-server

I'm trying to complete 2 select with 2 different SQL Server queries in the same HTML.

I'm using this code to complete 1

router.js

```
app.get('/bajatel', function(req, res, next) {
        var data = []
         request.query('select NLineas from tb_lineas', function(err, fields){
        if(err) { 
            console.log('error en la busqueda');
            return;
        }
        console.log(fields)
      // Pass the DB result to the templates  
        for (var i = 0; i < fields.recordset.length ; i++){

            data.push({NLineas: fields.recordset[i]})
        }
        res.render('bajatel.html', {Valuelist: data});
        console.log(data)
       });
    });
```

db.js

```
var sql  = require('mssql');
var config = {
  user     : 'sa',
  password : 'xxxxxxxx',
  server   : 'xxxxxxxx',
  database :  'db_test'
};

var connection = sql.connect(config, function(err) {
    if (err){
        throw err ;
    } else{
        console.log('connected');
    }

});

module.exports.connection = connection;
```

I want to add a second query in the app.get to have a second array:

```
 var motivo = []
request.query('Select DescMotivo from tb_Motivos', function(err, rows){
if(err){
   console.log('error en la  busqueda');
   return;
}
for (var i = 0; i < rows.recordset.length; i++){
 motivo.push({DescMotivo: rows.recordset[i]})
}
```

The final render should be:

```
 res.render('bajatel.html',{Valuelist: data, Motivolist: motivo})
```

but I don't know how to export the data to complete the array outside of the query.

the idea is to have 2  boxes with the queries options and they must select the default values

Could somebody help me?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: And in this case show us the second query and current and desire html render